# Объясните, что означает данная строка

Tags: python

Что означает эта `count[section(int(input()))] += 1` строчка в данном коде ?

```py
def section(k) :
    if k <= 36 :
        return (k - 1) // 4
    else :
        return 8 - (k - 37) // 2
        count = [0] * 9
        n = int(input())
        for i in range(n) :
            count[section(int(input()))] += 1
            ans = 0
            curr = 0
            for i in range(9) :
                if count[i] == 6 :
                    curr += 1
                    ans = max(ans, curr)
                else :
                    curr = 0
                    print(ans)
```

Comment: прибавить единицу к элементу списка `count` под индексом `section(int(input()))`, то есть вызов функции от целого числа, введенного с клавиатуры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count[section(int(input()))] += 1
```

Развернём в

```
text = input()  # Ввод строки 
value = int(text)  # Преобразование к целому числу
sect = section(value)  # Рекурсивное применение функции section
count[sect] += 1  # Увеличение элемента с номером sect на 1
```